# Make Route Event Layer snaps event points to vertexes?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, linear-referencing, route

In ArcMap 10.2.1 I have made a route event layer using the geoprocessing tool in the normal way, trying to add equidistant route events along a route every 1.6 meters.  This works fine in all the route segments, as I see points evenly spaced along the length---- except at the vertexes.  At every vertex, two of the expected route event points on each side of the vertex have been snapped to the vertex, like:

--P--P--P--P------V------P--P--P--P--

Under the V, there are the four snapped (misplaced) event points.

I expect:

--P--P--P--P--P--P-V-P--P--P--P--P--

Is this a setting somewhere? I do not want the nearby points to snap to a vertex.  Changing the ArcMap editor vertex snapping settings has no effect.

Comment: We've run into similar or same issue. Locate features along route insists on snapping all points to vertices of the route. Even points previously snapped to the line will be moved to a vertex. 10.2.2